# Why return statement is not working in this dart program?

Tags: flutter, dart

**MY Code:**

```
String fun(int age, String name)
{
  print("hi");
  return 'My name is $name and i am $age';
}

void main()
  {
   print("Hello! Good Morning good people.");
   fun(21,"Jasraj");   
  }
```

**Output:**

Hello! Good Morning good people.
hi

**My Question:**
Why return statement is not working?

**See Image**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`fun` return a string and to show, you need to wrap with print method.

```dart
void main() {
  print("Hel`enter code here`lo! Good Morning good people.");
  print(fun(21, "Jasraj"));
}
```

Or

```dart
  String result = fun(21, "Jasraj");
  print(result);
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can explore more about [functions](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions)

Answer (score 0):

in void main, return only works if you print it so
print(fun(Int variable, String Variable))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).